# Multiple implementations in Guice with indirect dependency

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

My Java code uses multiple implementations of an interface (BugTemplate in the example below), where the bound implementation depends on context.

In Guice, I believe the proper way to accomplish this is with BindingAnnotations. However, my use case is different than the canonical example, in that the context is one level removed from the interface's implementation.

Summarizing the possible dependencies:

> FooBugFinder -> BugFiler -> FooBugTemplate
>
> BarBugFinder -> BugFiler -> BarBugTemplate
>
> etc.

Example code:

```
class FooBugFinder {
  // ...
  public findBugsAndFileThem() {
    List<Bug> bugs = findBugs();
    bugFiler.fileBugs(bugs);
  }
  @Inject
  FooBugFinder(BugFiler bugFiler) {
    // BugFiler should have been instantiated with a FooBugTemplate.
    this.bugFiler = bugFiler;
  }
}

class BugFiler {
  // ...
  public fileBugs(List<Bug> bugs) {
    List<FormattedBugReport> bugReports = bugTemplate.formatBugs(bugs);
    fileBugReports(bugReports);
  }
  @Inject
  BugFiler(BugTemplate bugTemplate) {
    // The specific implementation of BugTemplate is context-dependent.
    this.bugTemplate = bugTemplate;
  }
}

interface BugTemplate {
  List<FormattedBugReport> formatBugs(List<Bug> bugs);
}

class FooBugTemplate implements BugTemplate {
  @Overrides
  List<FormattedBugReport> formatBugs(List<Bug> bugs) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

My first thought is to annotate the ctor as follows:

```
FooBugFinder(@Foo BugFiler bugFiler) { }
```

However, how would Guice know to apply that annotation when injecting arguments to BugFiler's constructor?

In other words, FooBugFinder needs a BugFiler instance which was instantiated with FooBugTemplate.
BarBugFinder needs a BugFiler instance which was instantiated with BarBugTemplate.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this is the so-called "robot legs" problem. Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions, and scroll down to "How do I build two similar but slightly different trees of objects?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a private module that exposes an annotated `BugFiler` object:

```
abstract class BugFilerModule extends PrivateModule {
  private final Class<? extends Annotation> annotation;

  BugFilerModule(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
    this.annotation = annotation;
  }

  @Override protected void configure() {
    bind(BugFiler.class).annotatedWith(annotation).to(BugFiler.class);
    expose(BugFiler.class).annotatedWith(annotation);
    bindBugTemplate();
  }

  abstract void bindBugTemplate();
}
```

Then, when you create your injector:

```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
        new BugFilerModule(Foo.class) {
          @Override void bindBugTemplate() {
            bind(BugTemplate.class).to(FooBugTemplate.class);
          }
        },
        new BugFilerModule(Bar.class) {
          @Override void bindBugTemplate() {
            bind(BugTemplate.class).to(BarBugTemplate.class);
          }
        },
        /* other modules */);
```

and you can create a `FooBugFinder` in the way you suggest:

```
public class FooBugFinder {
  @Inject
  public FooBugFinder(@Foo BugFiler fooBugFiler) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- the syntax is a bit cumbersome, but it definitely works.